# Foundation 5 top-bar responsive height

Tags: responsive-design, navigation, zurb-foundation

I just want to change the height of Foundation 5's Top-Bar Navigation depending on the screen size.

For example the height of the top-bar on **small-screen** should be **100px**, 
on **medium screens and larger** the height should be **150px**.

Thanks for your help!
Markus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your css

```
.top-bar {
  height: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
}
```

Media query for mobile screens

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) { 
  .top-bar{
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
  }
}
```

Comment: I had to put the class also inside the media Query. than it worked for me:

.top-bar {
      height: 150px;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 40em) { 
        .top-bar {
            height: 100px;
        }
    }

Comment: This is not a way that works. The <a> elements inside the menu picks up the topbar-height parameter and will not follow the height of the top-bar.